# python finding multiple occurrences between 2 delimiter

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to find multiply occurrences between 2 delimiters using regex.
Unfortunately i can't figure out how.
The 2 delimiters are ' and ':

```
import re
string = "'lightOff' 'lightOn':,'lightOff' 'ovenOff' 'ovenOn': None 'radioOn': 'radioOff'"
print string
print 'newString', re.findall("^'(.*?)':", string)
```

I only get the first match

```
'lightOn'
```

What i want is to get the 3 substrings between ' and ':

```
'lightOn'
'ovenOn'
'radioOn'
```

Comment: How can you get `stageOn` from the source string, its not even in it?

Comment: should be 'lightOn' fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the anchor. `^` and `$` are the anchors in a regex pattern. Also, when you match between two `'`, it'll return the string `'word1' 'word2':` as output, instead of only `'word2':`. Try to match everything between two `'` which isn't the character `'` itself.

```
re.findall("'([^']+)':", string)
```

will work.

Comment: This will not find empty Strings between the delimiters. So if you need to capture empty strings too you should use `"'([^']*)':"`

Answer (score 0):

> What i want is to get the 3 substrings between ' and '

Just try without capturing groups with [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [**Character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
(?<=')[^']+(?=':)
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wJ8nY0/4)

A worth reading  post on **[`✽ Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#lazy_warning)** on **performance** and **back-tracking**

> However, a lazy quantifier has a `cost`: at each step inside the braces, the engine tries the lazy option first (match no character), then tries to match the next token (the closing brace), then has to backtrack. Therefore, the lazy quantifier causes `backtracking` at each step.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would also work,

```
'[^']*'(?=:)
```

And the python code would be,

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "'lightOff' 'lightOn':,'lightOff' 'ovenOff' 'ovenOn': None 'radioOn': 'radioOff'"
>>> m = re.findall(r"'[^']*'(?=:)", string)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
'lightOn'
'ovenOn'
'radioOn'
```

If you don't want to include `'` in the final result then use lookahead and a lookbehind.

```
>>> m = re.findall(r"(?<=')[^']*(?=':)", string)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
lightOn
ovenOn
radioOn
```